# Como criar um plot com 2 histogramas sobrepostos?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, histograma

Suponha que eu tenha os seguintes dados de 2 grupos distintos.

```r
set.seed(1)
grupo1<-rnorm(400,6,2)
grupo2<-rnorm(200,8,2)
```

Como faço um histograma dos dois grupos na mesma tela, identificando cada um dos grupos com uma cor distinta e vendo a sobreposição dos 2 histogramas?

Comment: +1 Muito massa essa pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível fazer com as funções base, colocando cores semi-transparentes:

```
 h1<-hist(grupo1)
h2<- hist(grupo2)
plot(h1, col=rgb(0,0,1,1/4),
     main = "Histogramas",
     xlab = "x",
     ylim =c(min(min(h1$counts), min(h2$counts)), max(max(h1$counts, max(h2$counts)))),
     xlim=c(min(min(h1$breaks), min(h2$breaks)), max(max(h1$breaks, max(h2$breaks)))))
plot(h2, col=rgb(1,0,0,1/4), add=T)
```

Note que é preciso ter cuidado em colocar os limites `xlim` e `ylim` para que o segundo e o primeiro gráfico caibam juntos na tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para fazer com o `ggplot2` você precisa que seus dados estejam no formato `data.frame`:

```
set.seed(1)
grupo1<-data.frame(valor=rnorm(400,6,2), grupo="grupo1")
grupo2<-data.frame(valor=rnorm(200,8,2), grupo="grupo2")
```

Note que para reproduzir o mesmo gráfico que fizemos com o base, o `binwidth` de cada grupo tem que ser diferente (mas não necessariamente isso é melhor, pois no comando `hist` isso foi escolhido automaticamente, estou fazendo para ilustração):

```
ggplot(grupo1,aes(valor, fill=grupo)) + 
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5, position = 'identity',binwidth = 1)+
  geom_histogram(data=grupo2,alpha = 0.5, position = 'identity',binwidth = 2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]